# what is the difference between a function with generic type parameter and non-generic function in typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I recently came across a scenario where I thought I might need to use generics and looked into the typescript documentation on [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) to understand it correctly. but I am still not clear about the different use cases for using generics over non generics.

what is the difference between the following snippets?

```
interface Type1 {
  name: string,
  age: 23
}

const function1 = (each: Type1) => {
   // some logic...
   return 'something';
}
```

and

```
interface Type2 {
  name: string,
  age: 23
}

const function2 = <Type2>(each: Type2) => {
   // some logic...
   return 'something';
}
```

I read the documentation for generics multiple times and tried to find the difference in code playground

## update 1

```
const genericTest = <T>(arg: T): T => { return arg; };
const genericTest1 = <T extends Test1>(arg: T): T => { 
console.log(arg.name); return arg; }; // this will work
const genericTest2 = <T>(arg: T): T => { console.log(arg.name); return arg; }; // error: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'T'

interface Test1 {
    name: string,
    age: number
}
const result1 = genericTest<Test1>({ name: 'vishnu', age: 29 });
console.log('result1::> ', result1);
```

what are some of the use-cases of unrestricted generics (without using extends)??
if I am using unrestricted generics, how can i use the arg  inside the function?

## Update 2

I found a implementation of a custom array.find method and converted it into generics function. I think I have a pretty good idea of what generics are used for.

loosely speaking, ***generics is about the ability to handle multiple types safely rather then the type itself***

```
interface Array<T> {
customFind(o: CB<T>): T | undefined;
}
interface CB<T> {
    (each: T, index?: number, array?: Array<T>): boolean;
}
Array.prototype.customFind = function<T>(callback: CB<T>) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) if(callback(this[i], i, this)) return this[i]
}
const array: number[] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
const result = array.customFind((each)=>{
    return each===1
})
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Generic functions take *type* arguments (at compile time) in addition to whatever regular arguments it takes. But `function2` does nothing with its type parameter and you've shadowed the name of an interface.  Let's take this down to the value level by analogy: what's the difference between `const t1 = {name: "", age: 23}; const f1 = () => {return "something"};` and `const t2 = {name: "", age: 23}; const f2 = (t2) => {return "something"}`?  If you can answer that then you essentially have the answer to your question. Can I turn that into an answer or is something still unclear?

Comment: FYI: Your second example does _not_ reference `Type2`. Instead it creates a generic type parameter named `Type2` for use within that functions types that shadows the `Type2` declared above it.

Comment: @jcalz sorry couldn't understand the example. only difference I can see is that t1 and t2 are same and t1 is not being used.

Comment: @AlexWayne so, Type2 inside the function is different from the interface outside the function?

Comment: @VishnuRoshan Yes. When you define a generic type parameter like `<T>(arg: T) => void` the `<T>` only ever creates the generic.  If you wanted to _constrain_ that generic you can reference other types like `<T extends OtherType>(arg: T) => void`. In these examples `T` is scoped to just the function that created it. And if another `T` type was declared in a parent scope of this function, it would be shadowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic type parameter in a function is useful when you need to reference or reuse a type in some way. In your examples you do not do this.

But let's say you have a function that logs a value and then returns it.

Without generic the best you could is this:

```
const logAndReturn = (arg: unknown): unknown => {
  console.log(arg)
  return arg
}

const userA: User = { name: 'Foo', age: 30 }
const userB: User = logAndReturn(userA) // error: cannot assign unknown to user
```

Now with generics:

```
const logAndReturn = <T>(arg: T): T => {
  console.log(arg)
  return arg
}

const userA: User = { name: 'Foo', age: 30 }
const userB: User = logAndReturn(userA) // fine
```

Now if I pass in a `User` I get a `User` back, but the function itself doesn't care *what* I pass in. So this function needs to be generic because the return type depends on the type of `arg`.

---

Another example, say you want a random element from an array.

```
function getRandomElement<T>(arr: T[]): T {
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
  return arr[index]
}

const users: User[] = [...]
const randomUser = getRandomElement(users) // returns object of type: User
```

Here you declare a generic `T` to be the type for members of the array. Accept an argument that is an array of `T`, and then return `T`.

Again, you need a generic here because the return type depends on a type that will only be known when the function is called with a specific type elsewhere in your code.

---

> if I am using unrestricted generics, how can i use the arg inside the function?

Your function typically wont care what the type is, but something downstream will. For example, in my `getRandomElement` function above it doesn't matter what the elements in the array actually are to this function, but that just sets the type that will be returned.

If you want to access specific fields of those values, then that is when you need to constrain it.

```
function filterCool<T extends { isCool: boolean }>(arr: T[]): T {
  return arr.filter(item => item.isCool)
}

const users = [{ name: "Abc", isCool: true }, { name: "Def", isCool: false }]
const coolUsers = filterCool(users) // { name: string, isCool: boolean }[]
```

Here we use `T extends { isCool: boolean }` because the function requires `isCool` to work, but we want to allow other fields as well.

---

> loosely speaking, generics is about the ability to handle multiple types safely rather then the type itself

A better way to say it is that generics allow you accept a type that may differ throughout your program, and it allows to reference whatever that type is elsewhere.

When one type in a function depends on another type in that function, that usually means you want a generic function.

Comment: can you check the update I made to the post?

Comment: See my updates. But also this question and are getting a bit long. If you have more questions, please create a new question post for them.